# Pythonic Way to Add Space Before Capital Letter If and Only If Previous Letter is Not Also Capital

Tags: python, regex

As the title says, I would like to add spaces before capital letters, but only if the prior letter is not also a capital letter. So `'HelloCHARLIE this isBob.'` should become `'Hello CHARLIE this is Bob.'`

Comment: I'm concerned about your logic as applied to names.  On some occasions, it would be normal to have a lowercase_uppercase sequence within the same name.  For example:  Hello McDougal this is McPherson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<![A-Z])(?<!^)([A-Z])

print re.sub(r"(?<![A-Z])(?<!^)([A-Z])",r" \1",x)
```

This works.See demo.Use a negative lookbehind to ensure preceding character is not Capital or start of string.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cH8vN2/1

Comment: with `re.sub(r"(?<![A-Z]|^)([A-Z])", r" \1", text)` I get the same error.

Comment: You can replace `(?<!^)` with `\B`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be

```
import re
string = 'HelloCHARLIE this isBob.'
re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', string)
```

prints

```
'Hello CHARLIE this is Bob.'
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for all column headers in a dataframe?